# How to export huge postgresql database in batches?

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql, csv

I have a huge database of over 20 million rows. I can export the whole database (which takes hours), but when I try to filter the data using python (pandas) pycharm fails (due to memory issues).

Is there a way to export the database in batches of 2 million rows for an example? Export 2mil, then other 2mil and have 10 files of 2 million rows at the end? This way I can filter every file using python (pandas) and I won't have memory issues.

Thanks!

Comment: Do the work in Postgres, not in Python.

Comment: It will be good if you can give some sample schema of your Database for size estimation of each row.

Comment: What is the average record volume?

Comment: This seems rather broad, see [help/on-topic] and [ask]. Have you done any research?

Comment: I try to do the work in Postgres but it takes up 20gb+ of my ram and eventually crashes if I do any SQL. This is why I just export the whole database.                                    I have no knowledge on databases and use simple SQL conditions example: SELECT * FROM mainDB where (random column) > 5                                                        There is a better way right?

Comment: Please share the average row volume, your table definition and a few records for example

Answer (score 1):

20 million rows isn't that many.  Unless each individual row is quite large or you are sending over a slow network, exporting should take minutes, not hours.

If it is a single table you want to split, that is a better task for COPY, not pg_dump.

```
psql -c 'copy pgbench_accounts to stdout'|split -l 2000000
```

You would type it at a terminal command prompt, just like you would pg_dump.  It will send out the table's data just like pg_dump does (except it does just the data, and for just one table), but then the linux command `split` breaks it up into files of 2e6 lines each.

Well, I see you didn't specifically mention pg_dump in your post.  When you said "export", what did you mean by that?  I had assumed you meant pg_dump.

Comment: What does copy do? I write this code in the terminal right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pg_dump to only extract one or more tables or exclude tables if that is going to help

Comment: I read about "dump" but I have no idea what it does. I'll look into it today, thanks!

Comment: pg_dump -t tablename  -U postgres -f tablename_date_etc.sql     dbname